# Big tables with generic fields as an alternative to EAV and Relational Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-attribute-value

### *What's the worst that can happen with below database design? Immediately or in the future?**

Im coding my micro MF and i am thinking of using the below schema for database. Which will be used by all modules in future. I have to use MySQL.  I am withholding the reasons and explanations so that someone will not close the question by saying that it is 'opinion based', as it happened earlier. Lets say that such is the problem at my hand, and this is the solution i must use. That being said :

```
Main Table
-------------------

primary_key   data_type   field1   field2   field3   field4   field5   field6   field7 
-----------   ---------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------ 

Attribute Table 1
-------------------

attribute_key1   primary_key   attribute_name   field1   field2   field3   field4   field5   field6   field7
--------------   -----------   --------------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------

Attribute Table 2
-------------------

attribute_key2   primary_key   attribute_name   field1   field2   field3   field4   field5   field6   field7
--------------   -----------   --------------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------

Attribute Table 3
-------------------

attribute_key3   primary_key   attribute_name   field1   field2   field3   field4   field5   field6   field7
--------------   -----------   --------------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
```

Attribute keys of each table may introduced to each other.

Field types can be spread out in any format appropriate; Maybe two of them longtext, one of them bigint or one of them tinyint one of them varchar.

data_type is the unique identifier of the data type. Say, Blog posts. primary_key is the key for the main identity (on top of the tree). Attributes are related to the main identity, and attached to the identity through primary_key.

As an example of how a module developer would use this, with a crude and simple example - using PHP :

- Define an array which expresses a data model and maps it to coder-readable fields :

  $var['models']['module_name']['blog_post'] = 
  array(
        'maintable'=>array('

  ```
          'primary_key' => 'post_id',
          'blog_post' => 'data_type',
          'title' => 'field1'
    '),
    'attribute_table1' => array(

           'attribute_key1' => 'category_id',
           'primary_key' => 'post_id',
           'field1' => 'tag'

    ),
  ```

  );

With this, the module dev defined a 'blog_post' Data Model which consists of post id, title and attached tags, spanning two tables. Belonging to module 'module_name'.

From that point on, if we say the module_name is blog, what the dev needs to do to access this data object would be something like :

$data_access->get_data('blog','blog_post',post_id);

(Module name, model name, data id)

Comment: Any reason new tables can't just be created for the modules/plugins? This is just reinventing the relational database, badly, in your DAL.

Comment: I dont understand why you are asking this again. The reason is explained in the question itself.

Comment: What  is the explanation ? I don't see it here?

Comment: It is the third paragraph.

Comment: I have explicitly titled the reasons with a bold title so it is now impossible to miss.

Comment: The question is off topic. The EAV debate has raged for 20+ years without clear resolution. As hardware become faster, the "benefits" of doing things "formally" keep slipping away, but DB zealots won't let go (cf NoSQL). I have inplemented both styles, both successfully. In any case, for every argument there is a counter argument - this subject is entirely opinion based.

Comment: I dont understand what is off topic about this question: Hardware has become faster, and yet even as Memory-Residing InnoDB tables, EAV format still provides horrible performance when you query more than one attribute - like in Wordpress - a few thousand posts only even. On the other hand, oScommerce, with its ages old crappy spaghetti code, can still handle extremely complex product and product attribute join queries with more than 5 joins and 30+ criteria much faster than Wordpress, over 70,000+ rows. And there is no 'opinion' in this either - i am asking advice about a SPECIFIC design.

Comment: @unity100: I don't see anywhere where you say why you can't just create new tables.

Comment: Im withholding the reasons for why because when i explained them when someone asked the reasons, it led to someone closing the question as 'opinion based' - which is totally unproductive. Therefore lets say this is the problem at hand, and this is the solution i must use. So im asking what i can expect to go wrong with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a hybrid approach with EAV -- put common fields into a table for each entity and then use EAV for uncommon fields.

The major downside with your approach is that the data itself is not self-documenting -- you don't know what it means.  In the future, this means that you have to develop all the metadata information as additional tables, and you will end up with an application that only you understand.  With regular relational tables, the table and column names are descriptive.  With an EAV approach, the attribute names are stored with the values.

Additional downsides:

- You cannot implement indexing to speed access for particular elements.
- A given value for an attribute could be in any column, making it hard to get an "overall view".
- You are not using the power of the relational database.
- You cannot define foreign key relationships among the tables.

Comment: The question is that, common fields for each entity is not known. They may be anything depending on what kind of module a dev is coding. For concern of self-documenting, all the data models are loaded into the MF in module init time, and what kind of data schema is present for each module is known when the MF is loaded. I intend to provide methods in the Data Object to tackle such matters. I noticed that i didnt add the attribute_type field to attribute tables though sorry - i should have done it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you've said (I've implemented exactly as you suggested as it worked beautifully) although I disagree especially about the relevance of "power" of the relational database, which year by year is less and less impressive as the app layer becomes more and more powerful. See my comment to question.

Comment: @Bohemian What have you implemented exactly?

Comment: I implemented (years ago) a transaction database where the main entities were represented, but the transaction details were EAV, because the nature of the transactions varied considerably and new types were constantly being added. Using EAV meant no database change were required during the life of the business. It rocked.

Comment: What kind of hardware does this application run on? With what kind of memory, processor power. Is it an application exposed to the internet, usable by end users, or is it used only in intranet by a small amount of users. Can it handle multiple joins with multiple criteria?

Comment: @Bohemian . . . If the OP weren't tied to MySQL, I might suggest JSON fields or nested tables, but MySQL lags in this functionality.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : Combined with the comment he made under the question when he closed the question, it feels to me that Bohemian has concluded in his mind that "EAV is the answer" with the rationalization that hardware is much stronger now, and that he wrote a transaction database years ago and it rocked. He seems to think that everyone has access to dedicated database clusters and majority of websites are not hosted in shared hosting environments with a few dozen megabytes allowed per customer-process and modest allotment of cpu power.

Comment: @unity100 I was not saying that EAV is or is not "the answer". I am saying that discussing EAV is a subjective debate, so it's off-topic. It worked for me, it may or may not not work for you or others. The merits of EAV are IMHO "opinion based", which is why I closed this as off-topic. If you feel strongly that it is "on topic", vote to reopen - I won't intervene in the reopening process if you do.

Comment: @Bohemian Excuse me but when i combine your two comments, i arrive in the EAV is the answer conclusion. Actually you described a Hybrid, but for the purposes of this question it evaluates to same. You basically say that hardware is strong enough now. This may be the case for you, your clientele/company/target audience. That is not the case for mine. Thats common logic. This makes closing of this question an opinion-based move. Now i have to gather a total 5 votes to have the question reopened, just because of that. If enough people dont see the post or dont bother, it wont. Unproductive.